# header Location não esta direcionando pagina ( PHP )

Tags: php, header

```
<?php
    // conexão
    require_once'connect.php';

    // Sessão
    session_start();


    if(isset($_POST["usuario"])){

        $erros = array();
        $usuario = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST["usuario"]);
        $senha = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST["senha"]);

        if(empty($usuario) or empty($senha)){
            $erros[] = "<li> O campo Usuário/Senha precisa ser preenchido ! </li>";
        }else{
            $sql = "SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$usuario'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){
                $senha = md5($senha);
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1){
                    $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
                    mysqli_close($connect);

                    $_SESSION['logado'] = TRUE;
                    $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $dados['id'];

                    **header('Location: home.php');**
                }else{
                   $erros[] = "<li> Usuário ou senha não conferem.</li>"; 
                }

            }else{
                $erros[] = "<li> Usuário não cadastrado.</li>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Sistema de Login

```
    </header>
    <main>  

         <form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> method="POST">
            <h2> Login </h2>
            <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário">
            <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">

            <?php
                if( !empty($erros) ) {
            ?>

            <p> <?php foreach($erros as $erro){
                        echo $erro;
                } ?></p>

            <?php
                }
            ?>

        </form> 
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
```

**Tudo esta funcionando, porém ele nao redireciona para a pagina home.php, não sei o que pode ser.
Agradeço a ajuda. **

Comment: os arquivos home.php e o arquivo que tem as condições de acesso estão na mesma hierarquia de pastas? Fiz um exemplo do arquivo teste.php acessando arquivo home.php sendo que home.php está em uma pasta e o arquivo teste.php está fora da pasta. 'header( 'Location: ../testepasta/home.php' );'

Comment: a não ser esses asteriscos não vejo o porque não funcionar.

Comment: Nada relacionado ao erro, que a meu ver não existe no código. Apenas uma forma de economizar processamento. Do jeito que o código está, obrigatoriamente, se o usuário existir, vai realizar 2 SELECTS. Ora, se o usuário existir, vamos logo ao finalmente. Agora se login e senha não retornam, faça o outro SELECT com login para verificar se existe, se existir informe que senha não confere e caso contrário informe que Usuário não cadastrado. Veja a sugestão em https://anotepad.com/notes/njdb3w

Answer (score -2):

Imagino que o erro possa ser por você estar referenciando diretamente ao arquivo php, e não à uma URL válida.

tente trocar de:

```
header('Location: home.php');
```

Para:

```
header('Location: http://localhost/projeto/home.php');
```